# Score not incrementing when it's supposed to

Tags: android

What i'm trying to do is quite simple. I want to generate random numbers(rand1 & rand2) and have the user give the correct answer of the sum. There are 2 buttons and the correct answer could be on either one. I am using the randDecider variable to determine whether or not the correct answer should show up on the first or second button. The randDecider is either a 1 or 2.

The issue I am having is sometimes when I click on the correct answer, The score doesn't increment. And it turns out that sometimes when I press the wrong answer, the score increments. So i'm assuming it's a 50/50 chance the score will increment regardless if the answer is correct or not.

```
    protected void setRandom(View v) {

//Assigning random values to ints
        rand1 = r.nextInt(5) + 1;
        rand2 = r.nextInt(5) + 1;
        randDecider = r.nextInt(2)+1 ;

//The sum of the randoms
        sum = rand1 + rand2;

//Setting the texts of the random values
        randTV1.setText(rand1 + "");
        randTV2.setText(rand2 + "");

/*If the random deciding number is 1, set the correct answer
on the choice1 button*/
        if (randDecider == 1){
            choice1.setText(sum+"");
            choice2.setText(sum+1+"");

//If the correct answer was chosen, increment the score and set the text
            if(v.getId()==R.id.choice1){
                score++;
                scoreTV.setText(score+"");
            }
        }
/*If the random deciding number is 2, set the correct answer
to the choice2 button*/
        if (randDecider == 2){
            choice1.setText(sum+1+"");
            choice2.setText(sum+"");

//If the correct answer was chosen, increment the score and set the text
            if(v.getId()==R.id.choice2){
                score++;
                scoreTV.setText(score+"");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think I need more context on this code. When is this method being called? The problem could be that you are setting the text exactly at the time you're checking for the currently selected answer.

Comment: @Qwertycrackers The method is called whenever either buttons are clicked on

Comment: When you select the correct answer button, are you calling `setRandom()` then? If so, that is your problem as the variables are being re-created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest splitting the two distinct functions a) creating and presenting the problem to be solved and b) checking the response and then c) introducing a class variable to store the answer until another problem is presented (which would be after responding b) ).

So you could

- a) add a line in the class

  ```
  int correctanswer;
  ```
- b) Add a method for setting the problem e.g. setProblem (called initially and then within c))
- c) Add a method for checking the response e.g. setResponse which calls the setProblem method when the score has been adjusted. The setResponse method being called when either button is clicked.
- d) add a call to initially invoke the setProblem.
- e) set the 2 onclick listeners to call the setResponse method.

The following could be a resolution (based upon your question) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int score, correctanswer;
    TextView scoreTV, randTV1, randTV2;
    Button choice1, choice2;
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // get UI components
         scoreTV = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.score);
         randTV1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.rand1);
         randTV2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.rand2);
         choice1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.choice1);
         choice2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.choice2);

         // Initialise
         score = 0;
         scoreTV.setText(Integer.toString(score));
         setProblem();

         // Button Listeners
         choice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 checkResponse((Button)v);
             }
         });
         choice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 checkResponse((Button) v);
             }
         });
    }

    // Set the problem
    public void setProblem() {

        //Assigning random values to ints
        int rand1 = r.nextInt(5) + 1;
        int rand2 = r.nextInt(5) + 1;
        int randDecider = r.nextInt(2)+1 ;

        //The sum of the randoms
        int sum = rand1 + rand2;
        correctanswer = sum;

        //Setting the texts of the random values
        randTV1.setText(rand1 + "");
        randTV2.setText(rand2 + "");

        /*If the random deciding number is 1, set the correct answer
          on the choice1 button*/
        if (randDecider == 1){
            choice1.setText(sum+"");
            choice2.setText(sum+1+"");
        } else {
            choice2.setText(sum+"");
            choice1.setText(sum+1+"");
        }
    }


    // Check the user's response (called by onClick listeners)
    public void checkResponse(Button v) {    
        if ((new Integer(v.getText().toString()) == correctanswer)) {
            score++;
            scoreTV.setText(score+"");
        }
        setProblem();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your method, you have several lines which generate the random numbers and the decider. These are correct.

Then, you show the random numbers and place the answers on the correct buttons, which is presumably also correct.

However, at the same time, you check whether the correct button is selected. This means you're checking against the **last** button the user pressed, not their answer.

One way to fix this is to save the sum and correct answer positions for at least one rotation. Change your `setRandom` method to generate the numbers and set them to the screen as they are now, but also to save the correct answer to an outside variable.

Then, in the button's `onPressed` method, check whether the pressed button is correct, increment the score, and call `setRandom` to put a new question on the screen.

The problem in your code stems from the fact that you check the answer right as you put the question on screen. Happy programming!

Comment: OK I see what you mean now.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" the answer if it helped you